# How to disable View State MAC globally?

Tags: .net, asp.net, viewstate

I'm tired of including

```
EnableViewStateMac="false"
```

in every page. How to do that globally?

Comment: For posterity's sake: By disabling ViewStateMAC, you're allowing the ViewState to be tampered with by the client, so you can't really trust any of the data that's in there.

Comment: **DO NOT EVER THINK ABOUT THIS AGAIN** [Disabling view state MAC (and why you should never, ever, ever do it)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/09/understanding-and-testing-for-view.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can disable it on the [`<pages>` element in the web.config](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1271336869&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn$msdn$msdn&wreply=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354), like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages enableViewStateMac="False" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! This will introduce a security vulnerability into your application (see comment below by @has-altaiar ) and this video: http://vimeo.com/68390507

Answer (score 7):

The answer above explain to you how to set it in the Web.Config, but look at MSDN and you will see what it says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac.aspx):

> This attribute should never be set to false in a production Web site,
>   even if the application or page does not use view state. The view
>   state MAC helps ensure the security of other ASP.NET functions in
>   addition to view state.