# How to solve MAC error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config, web-hosting

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: How to solve this error Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: Don't just re-post what you already posted. Please answer my question: *What did you check?* That error message gives you a few different places to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, you should [synchronize machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) across all the servers in the cluster.

Not recommended, but you can also [disable view state mac checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645468/how-to-disable-view-state-mac-globally). This will however allow users to tamper with the viewstate data.