# how to solve viewstate MAC failed in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I'm facing this problem on server and localhost both place

> Error:
>
> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net Validation of viewstate MAC failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840899/asp-net-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed)

Comment: Levi has the right answer - There is a KB article that addresses your question at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue add following line in your web.config file under `<system.web>`

**`<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto>`**

Also read about web garden vs web farm [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114910/What-is-the-difference-between-Web-Farm-and-Web-Ga)

Thanks,
Ashish
[Soigne Technologies Pvt Ltd](http://www.tech-soigne.com)

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx page, keep the EnableViewStateMac value as false. This will be in the first line of your aspx page. For example

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" EnableViewStateMac="false"%>
```

Comment: Hello, I'm tried by using this tag in config and aspx page <pages enableViewStateMac="false"> all viewstate are stop working... please give me other solution...

Answer (score 0):

Two option

1. Either Disable ViewStateMac equal to false
2. Or Configure MachineKey in Web.config ( It should not be auto generate)

Comment: How can i disable this ViewStateMac ?

After disable should my ViewState tag will work ?

Comment: Yes. Answer of this question may help you to disable for your application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645468/how-to-disable-view-state-mac-globally