# how to solve "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" error while using form in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to use a post method in a form using asp and C# , but Validation of viewstate MAC failed error happens
here is my code :

```
<body>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <label>User Name : </label>
    <input id="u" runat="server"/>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <label>Password : </label>
    <input id="p" runat="server" />
   </div>
   <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Enter"/>
   <label id="notificationLabel" />
</body>
```

i tried both adding machin key to web config that didnt work . just like this :

```
<machinekey validation="SHA1" validationkey="A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1B2C3D4E5" decryption="Auto" decryptionkey="A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1A1B2C3D4E5F6F6E5D4C3B2A1" />
```

also in admin.aspx page i added these but still not working :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin" EnableEventValidation="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewStateMac="false" EnableViewState="false" %>
```

Comment: With just code like this, you shouldn't have a problem with MAC validation (although the button and inputs should be `runat="server"`). To get the error, you need to be doing something wrong, like manually changing the viewstate or controls on client-side.

Comment: i made both 'runat ="server"' but yet its not working and i get the "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" error

Comment: Did you see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970459) by Microsoft?

Comment: :D , i just wanted to add that i tried this and it didnt help too

Comment: Search first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645468/how-to-disable-view-state-mac-globally And if you decide to go by this make sure to have your own xss validations on input

Comment: as i told before i add EnableViewStateMac="false" in the page but i get the error yet

Comment: and what is xss validations ?

Comment: in fact when i add EnableViewStateMac="false" EnableEventValidation="false" i get this :
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple forms on the page. ASP.NET WebForms only supports a single form, which has to encompass all the `runat="server"` elements in the page. Or, you are manually modifying the form fields in JavaScript (`__VIEWSTATE`).

Comment: You are supposed to keep the machinekey a secret so if this post is traceable back to your website then you better generate a new one :)

Comment: This error can happen if a form is submitted before the page is completely loaded. I've seen it before on pages with very large viewstates (5+megs). Also you have no form tag for some reason.

Comment: i'm sorry its late to answer , but i had a dead line for a wpf project and i was busy with that , but finally i could find this error by adding EnableViewStateMac="false" in the web config , but when i added it in the page it couldnt solve the problem i dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add :

```
  <pages enableViewStateMac="false" />
```

in the web config file .

Comment: Make sure you understand the security ramifications of doing this. "This attribute should never be set to false in a production ...". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: exactly this was my question because as i read its not a safe way and its the best way to invite hackers for you website , but nothing else worked for me , as u can see above i add machinkey manually but i dont know why it didint help